# How can I insert records into Postgres with RLS when user has `grant all` perms and a loose policy

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-level-security

I'm new to Postgres' RLS feature.  I believe I'm following the documentation appropriately, but am getting unexpected behavior. Consider the following case:

- i have a table named `report_files`
- this table has a simple policy, `policy <name> for all using (true)`
- the user has `grant all` permissions on the table (`grant all on all tables in schema testing to testuser;`, along with `grant execute on all functions ...` and `grant usage` for the schema as well)
- the user can now read all fields in the table, **but  cannot `insert` records, against expectation**

Here's a **really short snippet** from **psql** demonstrating the aforementioned: https://gist.github.com/cdaringe/85dd9a7b1278afe4770869dc494216f3

I have set a permissive policy, which clearly evaluates OK as evidenced by the successful `select` command.

What can I troubleshoot to get the `insert` to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ERROR: permission denied for sequence report_files_id_seq

You need to grant permission to use the `report_files_id_seq` sequence. Granting permission to a table does not grant permission to a sequence. They are completely separate. A sequence is often used *by* the table as part of the `DEFAULT` value, but it's not *part* of the table.

You can grant permission to the sequence with:

```
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCE report_files_id_seq TO testuser;
```

Or to grant permission to all sequences** in a particular schema:

```
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA <insert schema name here>
```

`ALL` is equivalent to `USAGE, SELECT, UPDATE`

** this does not give permission to sequences created after the command is run.

---

##### Do you need to use a sequence?

If you are using Postgres version >=10, and only use the sequence to have a primary key value generated, my preference is to avoid sequences altogether. You can do that by using an `IDENTITY` column. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    description TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

See [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

Comment: shouldn't the `grant all`s cover it?  i will try this soon, but seems strange that i would `grant all` for a table, then have to follow up and `grant all` for indicies on the table

Comment: In my experience, no. Altering a tables permission does not change permission on a sequence. Why this is the case I don't know...

Comment: does GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA <insert schema name here> affect the futurely created sequences or only the one that already exists at the moment of the command ?

Comment: @thesearentthedroids - no, it only affects sequences that were in existence when you ran that command. db fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7Ctkn9u1hokAcwnSgRova7/0

Answer (score 2):

As I cannot comment yet, I will add some input as an answer if anyone arrives on this thread like me today.

Yes, you have to grant permissions on sequence(s) separately, in addition to the privileges already granted on the table(s). In fact it is what you have to do.

Even if your table is dependant on the sequence object, they are both different objects from the RDBMS point of view, so they require distinct privileges.

As for your indices example, index in a sub-object of a table, and no additional privilege is required to be able to make use of indices so no further action than the index creation is needed.

Moreover, be careful to prefix the sequence name in case it is stored in a schema which is not the default one (`public`) and which is not in your `search_path`. 
If that is not the case, you may encounter a permission denied error even though you have all necessary privilege on the sequence you aim to work with.